# Relation between the prime density and Riemann's zeros?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, riemann-zeta

**Soft question**: Where is the connection between the zeros of Riemann's $\zeta$-funciton and the density of prime numbers?

Is there a short answer to this question, to get the overview? I once had a lecture about this topic, but it took several weeks to proof the prime number theorem using $\zeta$, so I lost track of the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

The Riemann hypothesis, about the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$, is equivalent to the following statement:
For any real number $x\ge 1$ the number of prime numbers less than $x$ is
approximately $Li(x)$ and this approximation is essentially square root
accurate. More precisely,
$$
\pi(x)=Li(x)+O(\sqrt{x}\log(x)).
$$
Here $\pi(x)=\sum_{p\le x}1$ is the number of primes up to $x$. This says that the distribution of primes has the best possible error term if and only if the Riemann hypothesis holds true.

Comment: This is about as much as I already knew. So what is the idea to proof this equivalence?

Comment: Well, more or less the same ideas as for the PNT, which took several weeks, as you said. Elkies has a relatively short proof, see page $4$ in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.02/pnt.pdf.